# console output does not appear in code wars

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some javascript exercises on code wars. I want to see what's going wrong in my programs by printing to the console, but nothing except the test results appears in the output window. Does anyone know how to print to the console in code wars? I can't find anything in their documentation.

```
function areYouPlayingBanjo(name) {
  // Implement me
  var person = name.split('');
  person[0].toLowerCase();
  console.log(person[0]);
  if(person[0] === 'r'){
    return name + " plays banjo";
  }
  else{
    return name + " does not play banjo";
  }
}
```

Comment: Without a code no one can help you

Comment: What value for `name` is being passed?

Comment: Rikke, rikke and Martin, but they all print name + " does not play banjo" I just want to know how to print to console in code wars because console.log isn't doing it

Comment: @BatScream "ReferenceError: print is not defined at areYouPlayingBanjo" is what i get for print(person[0]);

Comment: Okay, my bad ;-(, no `print` function.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("Print stuff to output here.");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer to the question, but more of an extended answer in order to document a chrome extension that can allow debugging in the console for codewars.

Install this chrome extension:
https://github.com/bojan88/Codewars-JavaScript-debugger

This allows you to use the `debugger;` statement to force the your code to run in the browser rather than the sandboxed environment on the codewars servers. Works great.

Caveat:  I don't know if this is safe. Use at your own risk.